# How to calculate the inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function in python?

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

How do I calculate the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the normal distribution in Python?

Which library should I use? Possibly scipy?

Comment: Do you mean the inverse Gaussian distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution), or the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), or something else?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  the second one: inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i mean the python version of "normsinv" function in excel.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

[NORMSINV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826772) (mentioned in a comment) is the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  Using `scipy`, you can compute this with the `ppf` method of the [`scipy.stats.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) object.  The acronym `ppf` stands for [*percent point function*](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda362.htm#PPF), which is another name for the [*quantile function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).

```
In [20]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [21]: norm.ppf(0.95)
Out[21]: 1.6448536269514722
```

Check that it is the inverse of the CDF:

```
In [34]: norm.cdf(norm.ppf(0.95))
Out[34]: 0.94999999999999996
```

By default, `norm.ppf` uses mean=0 and stddev=1, which is the "standard" normal distribution.  You can use a different mean and standard deviation by specifying the `loc` and `scale` arguments, respectively.

```
In [35]: norm.ppf(0.95, loc=10, scale=2)
Out[35]: 13.289707253902945
```

If you look at the source code for `scipy.stats.norm`, you'll find that the `ppf` method ultimately calls [`scipy.special.ndtri`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtri.html).  So to compute the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution, you could use that function directly:

```
In [43]: from scipy.special import ndtri

In [44]: ndtri(0.95)
Out[44]: 1.6448536269514722
```

`ndtri` is *much* faster than `norm.ppf`:

```
In [46]: %timeit norm.ppf(0.95)
240 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [47]: %timeit ndtri(0.95)
1.47 µs ± 1.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: I always think "percent point function" (ppf) is a terrible name. Most people in statistics just use "quantile function".

Comment: Don't you need to specify the mean and the std on both ppf and cdf?

Comment: @bones.felipe, the "standard" normal distribution has mean 0 and standard deviation 1.   These are the default values for the location and scale of the `scipy.stats.norm` methods.

Comment: Right, I thought I saw this `norm.cdf(norm.ppf(0.95, loc=10, scale=2))` and I thought it was weird `norm.cdf` did not have `loc=10` and `scale=2` too, I guess it should.

Answer (score 40):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

It can be used to get the ***inverse cumulative distribution function*** (**[`inv_cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.inv_cdf)** - inverse of the [`cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.cdf)), also known as the **quantile function** or the **percent-point function** for a given *mean* (`mu`) and *standard deviation* (`sigma`):

```
from statistics import NormalDist

NormalDist(mu=10, sigma=2).inv_cdf(0.95)
# 13.289707253902943
```

Which can be simplified for the *standard normal distribution* (`mu = 0` and `sigma = 1`):

```
NormalDist().inv_cdf(0.95)
# 1.6448536269514715
```

Comment: Great tip! This allows me to drop the dependency on scipy, which I needed just for the single stats.norm.ppf method

Comment: can you use that to transform data with uniform distribution to normal ?

Answer (score 21):

```
# given random variable X (house price) with population muy = 60, sigma = 40
import scipy as sc
import scipy.stats as sct
sc.version.full_version # 0.15.1

#a. Find P(X<50)
sct.norm.cdf(x=50,loc=60,scale=40) # 0.4012936743170763

#b. Find P(X>=50)
sct.norm.sf(x=50,loc=60,scale=40) # 0.5987063256829237

#c. Find P(60<=X<=80)
sct.norm.cdf(x=80,loc=60,scale=40) - sct.norm.cdf(x=60,loc=60,scale=40)

#d. how much top most 5% expensive house cost at least? or find x where P(X>=x) = 0.05
sct.norm.isf(q=0.05,loc=60,scale=40)

#e. how much top most 5% cheapest house cost at least? or find x where P(X<=x) = 0.05
sct.norm.ppf(q=0.05,loc=60,scale=40)
```

Comment: PS: You can assume 'loc' as 'mean' and 'scale' as 'standard deviation'