# equivalent of Matlab's gaminv in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, gamma-distribution

I would like to translate the following Matlab code in Python:

```
 tau=40 %scale parameter
 a=3 %shape parameter
 t = gaminv(0.90,a,tau);
```

The code returns t = 212.8928.  I've tried:

```
 import scipy.stats.distributions as dist
 tau=40
 a=3
 t = dist.invgamma.cdf(90, a, scale = tau)
```

but the python code doesn't return the same t value.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You want the `ppf` ("percent point function", which is a somewhat less common name for the inverse of the CDF or quantile function) method of [`scipy.stats.gamma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html):

```
In [27]: from scipy.stats import gamma

In [28]: gamma.ppf(0.9, 3, scale=40)
Out[28]: 212.8928135133684
```

See also [How to calculate the inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626994/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-the-normal-cumulative-distribution-function-in-p); the distribution is different there, but it is basically the same question.

[`invgamma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgamma.html) is a different distribution.