# Python: Gaussian Copula or invers of cdf

Tags: python, inverse, cdf

Let's say I have a column x with uniform distributed values.
To these values, I applied a cdf-function.

Now I want to calculate the Gaussian Copula, but I can't find the function in python. I read already, that Gaussian Copula is something like the "inverse of the cdf function".

The reason why I'm doing it comes from this paragraph:

> A visual depiction of applying the Gaussian Copula process to normalize
>   an observation by applying  = Phi^-1(()). Calculating () yields a value  ∈ [0, 1]
>   representing the proportion of shaded area at the left. Then Phi^−1() yields a value 
>   by matching the shaded area in a Gaussian distribution.

I need your help, does everyone has an idea how to calculate that?

I have 2 ideas so far:

1) gauss = 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s)*e**(-0.5*(float(x-m)/s)**2)
--> so transform all the values with this to a new value

2) norm.ppf(array,loc,scale) 
--> So give the ppf function the mean and the std and the array and it will calculate me the inverse of the CDF... But I doubt #2

The thing is

```
n.cdf(n.ppf(0.95))
```

Is not what I want. The idea why I'm doing it, is transforming a not normal/gaussian distribution to a normal distribution.

Like here:

[Transform from a non gaussian distribution to a gaussian distribution with Gaussian Copula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMh1T.png)

Any other ideas or tipps?

Thank you very much :)

EDIT:

I found 2 links which are quite usefull:
1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197283/how-to-transform-an-arcsine-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution
2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125648/transformation-chi-squared-to-normal-distribution/125653#125653

In this posts its said that you have to

> All the details are in the answer already - you take your random variable, and transform it by its own cdf ..... yielding a uniform result.

Thats true for me. If I take a random distirbution and apply the norm.cdf(data, mean,std) function, I get a uniform distributed cdf

Compare: `import pandas as pd
data = [1.5]*7 + [2.5]*2 + [3.5]*8 + [4.5]*3 + [5.5]*1 + [6.5]*8
cdf=n.cdf(data, n.mean(data),n.std(data))
print cdf`

But How can I do the

> You then transform again, applying the quantile function (inverse cdf) of the desired distribution (in this case by the standard normal quantile function /inverse of the normal cdf, producing a variable with a standard normal distribution).

Because when I use f.e. the norm.ppf function, the values are not reasonable

Comment: Do a google search for "python gaussian formula". You will get several useful hits.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help, but I couldn't find any helpful hits. Only this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626994/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-the-normal-cumulative-distribution-function-in-p   You think I can apply this to my problem? Just norm.ppf()??

Comment: So is it correct, that I can just apply the norm.ppf() function, add my mean and my std to it, and then I "transform" my f.e. uniform distribution to a normal distribution?

Comment: You need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform IIRC

Comment: Could you explain a bit please? As you can see, I don't have a lot of knowledge about that. So the Probability Integral Transformation is the same as the inverse of cdf / Gaussian Copula? Because the result of your link is to transform it into uniform distribution, but I want normal distribution :) What are the dependencies? Thank you :)

Comment: These 2 links are (at least I think) helpfull, but I have no idea how to build that in python: 1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197283/how-to-transform-an-arcsine-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution  2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125648/transformation-chi-squared-to-normal-distribution/125653#125653 Any help?