# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.. why I am getting this error?

Tags: python, matlab

This is my matlab code which is working finely:

```
r=log2(1+gamma)-sqrt(V(gamma)/n)*qfuncinv(target)/log(2);
V=@(x)1-(1+x).^-2;
```

I am converting this in python as follows:

```
r=math.log2(1+gamma)-math.sqrt(V(gamma)/n)*(abs(norm.ppf(target))/math.log(2))
```

where,

```
gamma = 1 x 4957 double, n=256, target= 10**-5
```

and v

```
def V(x):
    return (x)-(1+x)**-2
```

how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: You still missing the details, what us `norm` here ?

Comment: from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699836/how-to-use-norm-ppf#:~:text=The%20method%20norm.ppf%20%28%29%20takes%20a%20percentage%20and,to%20a%2C%20%27One-tail%20test%27%20on%20the%20density%20plot. The method norm.ppf () takes a percentage and returns a standard deviation multiplier for what value that percentage occurs at. It is equivalent to a, 'One-tail test' on the density plot. in MATLAB its equivalent is qfuncinv

Comment: Actually, this code works for me. Can you post your full trackback here ?
And `gamma = 1 x 4957` what is this mean ? I assumed it's 1*4957.

Comment: gamma is an array of values type double with a range from 1 to 4957

Comment: And how `1+gamma` this going to work? Is it inside a loop?

Comment: I took this code from matlab which I am trying to change in python: r=log2(1+gamma)-sqrt(V(gamma)/n)*qfuncinv(PER_target)/log(2); this is the matlab code sorry I am not able to make it in the code format in comments I don't know why there is no option for me

Comment: In this case, gamma should be a constant value, not a range then only you can apply  `gamma` directly into the equation.

Comment: I checked it in matlab. it is double and  yes it is like a vector from 1 to 4957

Comment: I think you need to revise the question accordingly mention that you converted the code from Matlab, so the experts in python+matlab can help you out.

Comment: I would suggest using numpy, not math. But in ant case, the error should tell you the function that throws it too.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy, if you are working with numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
r=np.log2(1+gamma)-np.sqrt(V(gamma)/n)*(abs(norm.ppf(target))/np.log(2))
```

`math` mostly only accepts 1 number as input, i.e. python scalars. so when `V(gamma)/n` happens to be an array that is larger than size 1, and `math.sqrt` expects a python scalar, you get:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
```

Comment: yes, you are right I changed it but there is more in the code modify.

Comment: @Mario hat do you mean "code modify"?

Comment: I mean there is more to modify in my own code. this is just one line of code