# Inverse of cumulative density function for Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, quantile, cdf

A percent point function or quantile function for distribution is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function,
[How to calculate the inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20626994/12947980)

i.e. For given probability & parameters, its output is the value of the random variable.

I know this is possible for a univariate case in python as-

```
from scipy.stats import norm    
norm.ppf(0.95, loc=10, scale=2) # mean=10,variance=2, probability=0.95

Out[34]: 0.94999999999999996  # x value corresponding to given probability
```

Can somebody tell me a function similar to this for a **multivariate case** in Python or R?

Comment: the exact duplicate (along with its answer) of this very same question is found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/530488/354951). in a nutshell: **it doesn't exist**.