# Call SciPy from MATLAB using Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I would like to compute the [inverse CDF of Student T distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) using MATLAB without the statistic toolbox but with the help of Python and SciPy, see as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627638/7556646.

The following code running from MATLAB R2023a using Python 3.9.13

```
py.scipy.stats.t().ppf(0.975, df=4)
```

gives me the following error:

```
Error using _distn_infrastructure>__init__
Python Error: TypeError: _parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'

Error in _distn_infrastructure>freeze (line 824)

Error in _distn_infrastructure>__call__ (line 829)
```

The argument `df` is provided but not recognized. I don't understand why? See as well https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/python-function-arguments.html

For a normal distribution I can use SciPy from MATLAB:

```
py.scipy.stats.norm().ppf(0.975)
```

returns `1.9600` as expected.

In Python I can do it:

```
>>> scipy.stats.t.ppf(0.975, df=4)
2.7764451051977987
```

Comment: If in Python you can call `t.ppf(0.975, 4)`, then in MATLAB you should do the same thing. `df=4` is valid in MATLAB for keyword arguments only, but `df` is a positional argument. (The docs you link specify the function as `ppf(q, df, loc=0, scale=1)`, the first two are positional arguments, the latter two are keyword arguments.) Note that you need to use MATLAB syntax, not Python syntax.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `py.scipy.stats.t().ppf(0.975, 4)` throws as well an error. `py.scipy.stats.t(df=4).ppf(0.975)` returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work:

```
>> py.scipy.stats.t(df=4).ppf(0.975)

ans =

    2.7764
```